# Follow a post's share/like/comment

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-like, restfb

I am working in a website.And my website has it's internal registered users(also having user's facebook email-id and uid in my website database). In my website homepage I have facebook like button. Lets M1,M2,M3 are three registered member in my site. When M1 likes a content of my website it is shown on M1's wall. Then M2 likes/shares the post from M1's wall, and it is shown on M2's wall, Again M3 likes/shares the post from M2's wall, and it is shown on M3's wall. I want the events(along with uid of the liker/sharer) when M2/M3 likes/shares the post,so that I can do some activity based on the event for the corresponding user.

If it is possible to get the details on real time will be best, Otherwise any batch processing is also  acceptable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have the post_id, you can access it's data (including likes and comments) by sending a GET request to `https://graph.facebook.com/POST_ID`.

This will return JSON data related to that post that you can read and use.
See here for more details: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/post/

This is not yet available for real-time subscribing, so batch requests are your only option at this time.

Comment: It looks nice, But If I do this as a batch job, then every time I run the job will return the old records also. Is there any way to filter out only the new(activities done after I ran the batch job last time) likes/shares. Other wise  day by day the record will grow in huge.

Comment: It would, yes.
Unfortunately, as posting is not supported for real-time updating yet, there isn't really a better way. Yet.

Comment: Can u suggest me the way,how can I filter only the newest like/share those are not processed in my system yet.And from the  https://graph.facebook.com/POST_ID request I am getting only the no of shares, but not the POST_ID/uid who is sharing the post. Pls suggest the the right way

Comment: In order to filter out the newest likes/shares, perhaps you could store the post ID of each like/share on a post, then remove the ones that you have?

Unfortunately again, it seems that Facebook will not allow you to access sharing records, only comments and likes. However, even then, you may only be able to see the public comments/likes.